# php - creating img watermark

Tags: php, gd, watermark

```
<img id='imgt' src='../img/crop00.jpg' alt='img'>
<img id='imgtest' src='../img/crop00.jpg' alt='img'>
```

**js**

```
...
$.ajax({
    url: 'pro20.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {...},
    success: function(data) {
        $('#imgtest').attr('src', data);
    }
});
```

**php**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

GD library is turned on - checked with `print_r(gd_info());`

**pro20.php**

I'm trying to run **[this](http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php)** code

```
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('img/wmark.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('img/test.jpg');

$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

echo imagepng($im);  // my added line 28
```

Result:
- `#imgtest` is blank,
- in file system there is nowhere new img created
- error log:

`[:error] [pid 2736:tid 1580] [client ::1:59185] PHP Warning:  imagepng(): supplied resource is not a valid Image resource in ... pro20.php on line 28,`

Comment: you should probably use this http://image.intervention.io/ makes life way easier

Comment: @RajSharma, thanks for the info, but I need to know what is wrong with the above code.

Comment: Could it be that you `imagedestroy($im);` and then try and use `$im` in an `echo imagepng($im);` ???

Comment: You dont have to post to get the image because if you look at the php code you will see it is returning an image. You can just do this

    $('#imgtest').attr('src', 'url/of/your/pro20.php');

But in case you want to make it dynamic. Use get parameters instead of post. Pass the names of image in the url (if you pass url then urlencode them in client side)

    $('#imgtest').attr('src', 'url/of/your/pro20.php?png=stamp&jpg=main');

Comment: Also delete  the 'echo' line added by you

Comment: @RajSharma, Is there a way to echo the url of new created img inside `pro20.php`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I tried, without success.

Comment: Tried what::: Put the `imagedestroy($im);` after the `echo`

Comment: yes, and also delete the complete `imagedestroy($im);` line.

Comment: For that you will have to save the image using file. And return the URL to where you have saved

Comment: @RajSharma, do you mean using `file_put_contents...` ?

Answer (score -2):

There is nothing wrong with the code. The issue is likely that one (or both of the images) aren't being loaded correctly:

```
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('img/wmark.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('img/test.jpg');
```

Check that `img/wmark.png` and `img/test.jpg` exist and are valid images.

I've tested your code (with some slight modification):

```
<?php

$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('wmark.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('img.jpg');

$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

echo imagepng($im);
```

And I got this:

[image]

Nothing wrong with your code. The likely issue is that your images may not be valid png / jpg images. Please verify this.

Comment: This is tested, of course

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. The likely issue is that your images may not be valid png / jpg images. Please verify this.